# Scatterplot add a x line top of the line using Pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw a x line on the **Picture-1** exactly like **picture-2**. I also want to remove the arrow as marked with circle. Any suggestion or complete code will be greatly appreciate.

**Picture-1**
[image: Current Image]
**Code**

```
%-------------------------------------------
\begin{axis}
  [
  grid = both, %grid in the picture
  height=10cm, %height of the figure
  width=\textwidth,
  axis x line=middle,%remove the top x axis line
  legend style={draw=none}, %remove the box, options- none, white, black
  %-------------------------------------------
  xlabel style={xshift=-4.2cm}, %shifting the x line text -0.2
  xlabel style={yshift=-1.2cm}, %shifting the x line text -0.2
  ylabel style={yshift=0.3cm}, %shifting the y line text
  %-------------------------------------------
  ylabel=Accuradfdcy Value {\%},
  xlabel=number of best terms,
 ]
```

**Picture-2**
[image: Change the Image]

Comment: You explicitly specified `axis x line=middle` and there is an additional comment to explain what it does. So, why are you surprised?

Comment: Well axis x line=middle and axis y line=middle draw a line, but if I keep both I can not see the any line. This also move the x axis not like as my pictures :(

Comment: For a concrete answer you should provide a sample document that show the problem. This is done best by preparing a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: I don't get it, wouldn't removing `axis x line=middle` do exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1):

CW from the comments.

To restore the boxed axis, you need only remove the `axis x line=middle`.
I have used sample plots in my code here since I didn't have your plotted functions.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [
  grid = both, %grid in the picture
  height=10cm, %height of the figure
  width=\textwidth,
%  axis x line=middle,%remove the top x axis line
  legend style={draw=none}, %remove the box, options- none, white, black
  %-------------------------------------------
  xlabel style={xshift=-4.2cm}, %shifting the x line text -0.2
  xlabel style={yshift=-1.2cm}, %shifting the x line text -0.2
  ylabel style={yshift=0.3cm}, %shifting the y line text
  %-------------------------------------------
  ylabel=Accuradfdcy Value {\%},
  xlabel=number of best terms,
 ]
\addplot {x};
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]