# How to change the x axis position pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have trouble to shift the y axis. Is there any command to shift the y axis in the right direction (the first point where graph started) and start the graph exactly from the first point. Thanks.

[image: Is there any]

Comment: Please don't start multiple questions with tiny variations http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161444/scatterplot-add-a-x-line-top-of-the-line-using-pgfplots

Comment: I wanted to start the y axis exactly where the first point allocated. Now I edited the question, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Raid: Set `enlargelimits=false` (or `enlargelimits=upper`, depending on the exact behaviour you want).

Comment: @Raid, I updated my answer to include Jake's comment.

Answer (score 4):

To place the y axis in the right:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line*=bottom,
  axis y line*=right
]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

### UPDATE

As @Jake explained, you need `enlargelimits=false` to "shift" the y axis till reach the plot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, the your problem can simbly be solved by adding

```
[ymin=<Value>,ymax=<Value>]
```

to the options of the axis.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ymin = 50,
  ymax = 1400,
]
\addplot <Data goes here>;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Or, alternativly, change the domain option of the `\addplot`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[domain=50:1400] <Data goes here>;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```